# bitwise-and with HEX and CHAR in C

Tags: c, char, hex, bitwise-and

I'm really getting frustrated here. Trying to implement the CRC-CCITT algorithm and I found a very nice example on an Internet site.

There is one line whose output I completely don't understand:

```
unsigned short update_crc_ccitt( unsigned short crc, char c){
[...]
short_c  = 0x00ff & (unsigned short) c;
[...]
}
```

I want to calculate the CRC of the `"test"` string `"123456789"`. So in the first run the char 'c' is 1. From my understanding `short_c` from the first run should be equal to `1` as well, but when I print it to the console, I get `short_c = 49` for `c = 1`. How?

```
0x00ff in binary is: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
char 1 in binary is: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
bitand should be   : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `'1'` is a char (that is in string), simply `1` is number and `"1"` is a string, all are different.

Comment: Yeah I can see that now. I'm trying to transport the C code to matlab, so that's an additional difficulty for me besides being a rookie in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `1` has ASCII code 0x31 = 49. This is different from the character with ASCII code 1 (which is `^A`).

Comment: Thank you, that explains why 49. Didn't think of the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing characters and numbers, basically. The first letter in the string `"123456789"`is the character `'1'`, whose decimal value on most typical computers is 49.

This value is decided by [the *encoding* of the characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), which describes how each character is assigned a numerical value which is what your computer stores.

C guarantees that the encoding for the 10 decimal digits will be in a compact sequence with no gaps, starting with `'0'`. So, you can always convert a character to the corresponding number by doing:

```
const int digitValue = digit - '0';
```

This will convert the digit `'0'` to the integer `0`, and so on for all the digits up to (and including) `'9'`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!